# FileHelpers reading a complex csv file including an inner csv list in a class object

Tags: filehelpers

I am having a below csv file:

```
Employer EID,File Creation Date,File Creation Time,Salary Year and Month,Total Salaries,Total Records,,,
1006200,20032016,1031,201603,2200,1,,,
Record ID,Employee QID,Number of Working Days,Net Salary,Basic Salary,Extra hours,Extra Income,Deductions,Payment Type
1,29135617946,31,2200,2200,0,0,0,SALARY 
2,29135617947,31,2200,2300,0,0,0,SALARY 
3,29135617948,31,2200,2250,0,0,0,SALARY
```

Above file is having the first part as the employer information and the seond set of rows having the employees working with that along with their salary.

I want to create a complex class `Employer` which will be having the employees attributes along with a `List` of complex type named `Employee` that will include all the employees information.

Please help me by giving a direction/code to how can I achieve this using the FileHelpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MasterDetailEngine`. There is [an example in the documentation](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/MasterDetail/MasterDetailCustomSelector/).

You provide a *selector* class to enable FileHelpers to determine whether a record is a master record or a detail record.

```
private RecordAction ExampleSelector(string record)
{
    if (record.Length < 2)
        return RecordAction.Skip;

    if (IsMasterRecord(record)) // some way of identifying your master records
        return RecordAction.Master;
    else
        return RecordAction.Detail;
}
```

Then you can read your the file into your classes like this:

```
var engine = new MasterDetailEngine<Employer, Employee>(new MasterDetailSelector(ExampleSelector));

var result = engine.ReadFile("Input.txt");

foreach (var group in result) {
    Console.WriteLine("Customer: {0}", group.Master.EmployerEid);
    foreach (var detail in group.Details)
        Console.WriteLine("    Freight: {0}", detail.EmployeeQid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will give it a try and will reply back in case of any issues.